# Does anyone know how to create an event that can store the users message in a variable?

Tags: discord.py

I want to check if the users message is equal 'hello' for example. Here is the code I managed to write so far:

```
@client.event           
async def on_message(message):
    messageContent = message.content
    if len(messageContent) > 0:
        if messageContent == "hello":
            await message.channel.send('Do not say that!')
    else:
        return
```

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. Do you have any errors or something? How are you testing it? Did you pass ``intents`` to your bot?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code should be correct, i just made some adjustments but does this answer your question or what else were you looking for?

```
@client.event
async def on_message(message):
        
    # Storing the message in a variable and transforming the string into all lowercase #
    
    msg = message.content.lower()
    
    # Checking if the message is equal to hello
    if str(msg) == "hello":
        await message.channel.send('You are not allowed to say that!')
    else:
        return
```

Comment: This is what I did for intents ```intents = discord.Intents.default() client = discord.Client(intents=intents)``` is it right?

Comment: I run the code in VSC and test in a random server I made.

Comment: Try doing `intents = discord.Intents.default()
intents.members = True` and then do `discord.Client...` i think you forgot the intents.members, also did you toggle the presence intent setting in the dev portal?

Comment: I toggled **PRESENCE INTENT** but didn't have **SERVER MEMBERS INTENT**. Also by ```discord.Client...```do you mean ```client = discord.Client(intents=intents)```?

Comment: yea thats what i mean

Comment: Okay I tried that but it's still not printing anything..all other commands and events work. I think I might have forgot to import something. To do this only need to import: **discord** and **from discord.ext import commands** right?s

Comment: Could this be the error? 
```intents.members = True  
client = discord.Client(intents=intents)
client = commands.Bot(command_prefix = ';')``` I defined client 2 times I think this is the error. So should I change the second client to bot?